# How to override parameters in the docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I have extension.yaml with

```
 args:["key1","newValue"]
```

in my dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT  [ "/path/execution"]
CMD["-key1","value1","-key2","value2","-key3","value3]
```

When I will run the container does the keys : key2 and key3 will be saved or it will be deleted ?

also Can I move execution from the ENTRYPOINT   to the first parameter in the CMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the k8s [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod):

> The command and arguments that you define in the configuration file
>   override the default command and arguments provided by the container
>   image.
>   If you define args, but do not define a command, the default command
>   is used with your new arguments.

For your docker example the *entrypoint* field corresponds to k8s *command*. [This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes) is the relation:

```
| Docker field name | K8s field name |
|------------------:|:--------------:|
|    ENTRYPOINT     |     command    |
|       CMD         |      args      |
```

> If you supply only args for a Container, the default Entrypoint
>   defined in the Docker image is run with the args that you supplied.

**So, for your example you will end with the following command:**
`/path/execution key1 newvalue`

Comment: So all the parameters will be deleted in the CMD?

Comment: If I define CMD and ENDPOINT does in the end I will only 1 Run?